# Why are these 2 Morningstar charts apparently different?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, chart

I'm trying to compare two ETFs on www.morningstar.com.

I'm not able to understand why the **ending** of two price charts are different, i.e., in 2019.

[image: 3-year period]

[image: Maximum period]

In the 3-year graph, stock 1 is slightly higher in 2019. In the Maximum-lengh graph, stock 2 is far higher in 2019. I would have expected a difference between the two charts at the **beginning**, but not at the **end**.

I notice that volume is different in the 2 charts, but I can't make out any more than that. Could someone be kind enough to explain the difference between the two charts? And what's the proper way to compare two stocks? I want to know how to see the prices of 2 stocks over time, comparing them with each other, so I can see how both prices react to historical events.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE! Thank-you for the quick 'accept', but please revisit, and if a better answer is posted, I'm happy to see the award switched.   Most important, hope to see you again, a wealth of info here for the reading.

Comment: Thank you! I will surely do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The charts you have are 'percent change' along the Y-axis (vertical axis), and when comparing two assets, by definition, the graph starts at 0% at the date you chose to start.